# Handling char integers

Tags: c++, c

I have the following question. Is multiplying some character (as integer) by `-1` twice guaranteed to preserve the initial value?

So, I run some code, that marks a read character by multiplying it by `-1` (I'm living in an ASCII world, but any other symbol encoding would be also interesting to assess).

For example, suppose I've read an English letter `'a'` into variable `c`. To prevent further code of detecting this is the lower letter `I` want to multiply it by `-1`. After all this is an integer.

The code is basically a back-tracking solution to some problem, so after the decision tree branch was checked, I want to return the initial value of the letter to itself.

```
char c;
// some code gets the value
c *= -1;
// handle something
c *= -1;
```

The problem I *face*, is more of *What should I expect?*, rather than *Something does not work as expected*.

The characters I want to transform are always English letters, may be upper and lower.

From what I see in ASCII table both classes are in the range `0`..`127`.

So if

1) `char` is signed on my machine, I should expect *negative* letters to not be regular letters. Which is good.
2) char is `unsigned`. I have no clue. Should multiplication by `-1` be performed in `int`, then truncated to `char`?

Since, the standard does not require symbols to be ASCII, would the result in other encodings be different?

Comment: It won't work for `0`. Better to invert the m.s. bit, such as `c ^= 0x80`.

Comment: Use larger type. Maybe `assert(sizeof (int) > sizeof (char))`.

Comment: What does the standard say for multiplying an unsigned char by `-1` two consecutive times? I assume it's technically undefined behavior, but probably just works on most architectures.

Comment: `c & 0x80` will detect if MSB is set, char being signed or not...

Comment: @Aconcagua [the implementation at ideone](https://ideone.com/qBtFqu) does the multiplication of `unisgned char * int` in int

Comment: @WeatherVane Ah, OK, misinterpreted the other comment then...

Comment: @pmg That's even mandated by the standard (unless unsigned char and int happened to have same size, then unsigned int...). But there isn't anything gained at all when storing the value back in `c` – oh, well, unless you meant changing type of `c` to int as well?

Comment: I think if using one's complement system and when `char` is implicitly converted to `unsigned int` then the answer could not match. Like `(char)(1 * -1 * -1) = (char)(1 * 65534 * 65534) = (char)(4294705156) = 65532`

Comment: All in all this sounds like an XY problem. Perhaps you should ask for "using the unused bit in 8-bit chars to mark if it has been processed or not"

Comment: Yes @Aconcagua, use larger type (`int`) for `c`!

Comment: You mentioned other (non-ASCII) encodings. The alphanumeric characters in EBCDIC have codes above 128.

Comment: let say, I can't change the type, so it is not , that I'm not sure, and then should use something that is guaranteed to work. I have this code (and it probably works on most machines as it did on mine with VS2019) and I need to understand if it should work always (and from prev comment in EBCDIC world it does not)

Comment: I suggest that you fix the typo at the end of your second paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does multiplying some character (as integer) by `-1` twice guaranteed to preserve the initial value?

Well, only considering this question, yes, it does; in both cases, signed or unsigned, implicit integer promotion will occur (this is mandated by the standard) and the calculation will be done in `int` anyway (unless unsigned char and signed int happened to have the same size, then `unsigned int` instead).

Signed char: `x * -1` results in `-x`, resulting value fits into signed char, so fine, we can do the assignment (*exception*: -128; for this case, we get undefined behaviour! But as we can – considering ASCII – exclude this as input, we are fine...).

Unsigned char appears a bit more difficult: Again, we get `-x` as result, but need to place it into `unsigned char`. According to C standard, we need to add `UCHAR_MAX + 1` that many times until the value fits into the variable, in given case, we thus get `256 - x`. Second multiplication then results in `x - 256` as int value, again adding 256 until the value fits into the variable (remember, `x` itself did so already) eliminates the negative offset...

Side note: Adding `[TYPE]_MAX +1` as many times until the value fits into the variable is just cutting off the surplus most significant bits on a two's complement machine...

Solely the numerical value `0` would be problematic, as it wouldn't change its value. But as again this doesn't appear as valid input, we are fine.

> Since, the standard does not require symbols to be ASCII, would the result in other encodings be different?

No, no difference at all so far – whether char is signed or unsigned.

**However**: How do you want to detect the values identified as invalid? With ASCII (and compatible), it is simple, all values in question (English letters only!) are in range [0; 127], you identify the invalid ones by checking for `< 0` in case of signed char or `> 128` in case of unsigned char. The same applies for any other encoding that only uses either lower or upper half for the letters in question (this applies even for the infamous EBCDIC encoding, solely that this time the characters in question reside in [upper half of the [0; 255]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC#Code_page_layout) range and you need to invert the checks). This simple check, though, doesn't work any more if you encounter an encoding using both halves of the byte value range (I'm not aware of any). With EBCDIC, you might get into exactly this trouble with the word separators, though: e. g. the simple space character `' '`, but most punctuation marks, too, already lie in the other half than the letters (if you use such ones at all, you didn't mention...)!

Comment: Oh, the question does have a definite answer.

Comment: In EBCDIC, letters are indeed in the range 128..255, which means either `char` has more than 8 bits and can be signed or unsigned or **char has 8 bits and must be unsigned** on those platforms.

Answer (score 1):

> Is multiplying some character (as integer) by -1 twice guaranteed to preserve the initial value?

For input in the range `0 .. 127` the answer is **yes**

What happens are two things:

1) Integer promotion, i.e. the char is promoted to an integer and then multiplied by -1

2) Conversion from one integer type to another, i.e. `int` to `char`

If you are on a system with **signed** chars, there is nothing special going on as the standard requires the range to be at least `-127 .. 127`

If you are on a system with **unsigned** chars the conversion is done by adding UCHAR_MAX+1 to the result of the multiplication to get a number that can be stored in your unsigned char.

It will look like this when we consider it done with infinite precision.

```
// After first multiplication by -1
-c + UCHAR_MAX + 1

// After first multiplication by -1
-(-c + UCHAR_MAX + 1) + UCHAR_MAX + 1 --> c - UCHAR_MAX - 1 + UCHAR_MAX + 1 --> c
```

In other words - after myltiplying with -1 twice, we again have the original value.

BTW: Notice the zero (`0`) is a special case where your algorithm will not work as `0 * -1` is `0`, i.e. the marking will not work.

Comment: On a system with signed 8-bit `char`, a `char` value of `-128` would produce `128` which does not fit in a `char`. The C Standard does not guarantee that storing this value into a `char` will yield `-128`, hence multiplying the char by `-1` twice might fail to produce the original value, albeit a system with such a behavior would be extremely perverse.

Comment: @chqrlie Agree. But OP ask for input in the range 0..127 and this answer specifically states that: "For input in the range 0 .. 127 the answer is yes"  (in fact the answer is yes for the range -127 .. 127 but OP only looks at 0..127)

Answer (score 0):

See bit after ,before transform and transform back like this ,

maybe you will know what you really want

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){


    int i;

    char c='a';
    int d=c;//Give char to int
    printf("%d\n",d);
    printf("c's Binary is:\n",d);
    for(i=8-1;i>-1;i--){
        printf("%d",(c&(1<<i))>>i);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("d's Binary is:\n",d);
    for(i=8*sizeof(int)-1;i>-1;i--){
        printf("%d",(d&(1<<i))>>i);
    }
    printf("\n");

    c*=-1;

    printf("c's Binary(after) is:\n",d);
    for(i=8-1;i>-1;i--){
        printf("%d",(c&(1<<i))>>i);
    }
    printf("\n");

    c*=-1;

    printf("c's Binary(after2) is:\n",d);
    for(i=8-1;i>-1;i--){
        printf("%d",(c&(1<<i))>>i);
    }
    printf("\n");

    c=d;

    printf("c's Binary(d back to c) is:\n",d);
    for(i=8-1;i>-1;i--){
        printf("%d",(c&(1<<i))>>i);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

---

Comment: Do not you think, this code will produce the specific behavior for very specific machine? And mine and yours could have different one.

Comment: then why dont you do c=~c its bit reverse work in all machine c+-c=0 c+~c=0b11111111

Comment: I evaluate some code. So  it is not the question of how should I do it right. But rather, does the code in hand always work, or does it always work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using [std::bitset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) here. When you encounter a character, you set the corresponding bit using `std::bitset::set`. To check if the bit is already set, you'll have to use `std::bitset::test`.

Delimitations of this answer :

1.You are looking to encode your character. This answer does not do that but instead adds a `std::bitset` var that would help you keep track of the character you encounter.

2.If you do not reset the bit after each character, then on encountering the same character twice, it could lead to erroneous behavior.

Please find the sample code below :

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <bitset>         // std::bitset

const int gAsciiLimit = 128;

int main ()
{
  std::bitset<gAsciiLimit> foo;
  char letter = 'a';
  std::size_t temp = (std::size_t)(letter);

  foo.set(temp); // will set the 97th bit to true.
  std::cout << foo.test(temp) << std::endl;
  /* Other operations handled */
  foo.set(temp,false);
  std::cout << foo.test(temp) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are touching a very sensitive area in the C Standard: `char` default signedness.

As you are aware, the `char` type may be signed or unsigned by default on the various target platforms. This is a sad historical fact, and you should try and ensure that you program have the same behavior regardless.

The C Standard guaranties that the letters and digits are positive in the target character set so both lowercase and uppercase letters such as `i` and `I` are positive. Note however that some other characters, such as `é` encoded as `0xE9` in ISO-Latin-1 and the windows code page 1252 will be negative if the `char` type is signed (-23). Relying on negating the `char` values to prevent some processing is problematic since such negative `char` values would become positive and hence potentially undergo the transformation.

Multiplying a `char` value by `-1` is performed using type `int` (or type `unsigned int` if `char` is unsigned and has the same size as `int`, which happens only on some rare embedded processors). If type `char` is smaller than `int`, this multiplication cannot overflow, but the result should be stored into an `int` to avoid the implementation defined conversion in case the value exceeds the range of `char`, such as would be the case if `char` is unsigned. Indeed in most cases negating a `char` value twice should yield the original value, but the C Standard does not guarantee this behavior if the intermediary value is stored into a `char`.

Note also that `getc()` returns an `int` with either the negative value `EOF` or the positive value of the byte read from the stream converted as an `unsigned char`.

For your approach, you should store characters as `unsigned char` values, either in `unsigned char` variables or in `int` variables when you want to use the negation as a trick to prevent some special handling. Adding 256 might be a safer choice as it changes `'\0'` as well:

```
// Assuming 8-bit bytes
int c = (unsigned char)some_char;
// some code gets the value
if (some_condition)
   c += 256;
// handle something
c &= 255;
// back to previous value.
```